# How to fire a function after get data from another function in JQuery?

Tags: magento2, ajax, jquery

in my js file there is two function call CalculateAjax and Calculation like below,

```
require(['jquery'], function($) {

    var priceValue;

    //Ajax base price calculation
    var CalculateAjax = function(evt) {

        var set_width = jQuery('#width').val();
        var set_height = jQuery('#height').val();

        jQuery.ajax({
                showLoader: true,
                url: 'http://localhost/magento2/magento2/productconfiguration/index/ajax/',
                data: ({
                    Width: set_width,
                    Height: set_height
                }),
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json'
            })
            .error(function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            })
            .success(function(data) {
                priceValue = data.price_component;
                jQuery("#baseprice").html("Base Price: " + priceValue);
            });
    };
    $('#width,#height').on('change', CalculateAjax);

    //All other calculation
    var Calculation = function(evt) {

        var width = jQuery('#width').val();
        var height = jQuery('#height').val();

        //area calculation
        var area = (parseInt(width) * parseInt(height) / 1000000);
        jQuery("#area").html("Area: " + area);

        //circumeference calculation
        var circumeference = (2 * (parseInt(width) + parseInt(height)) / 1000);
        jQuery("#circumeference").html("Circumeference: " + circumeference);

        //frame color calculation
        var color = jQuery('#color').val();
        var framecolor = color * circumeference;
        jQuery("#framecolor").html("Frame Color Price: " + framecolor);

        //glass type calculation
        var glass = jQuery('#glass').val();
        jQuery("#glasstype").html("Glass Price: " + glass);

        //handle calculation
        var handle = jQuery('#handle').val();
        jQuery("#handles").html("Handle Price: " + handle);

        //post price calculation
        var centerposthorisontal = jQuery('#centerposthorisontal').val();
        var centerpostvertical = jQuery('#centerpostvertical').val();

        var HS = (parseInt(centerposthorisontal)) + 1;
        var VS = (parseInt(centerpostvertical)) + 1;
        var S = HS * VS;
        var postPrice = S * 102; //default bar price 102

        jQuery("#post").html("Center Post Price: " + postPrice);

        //bar price calculation
        var horisontalbars = jQuery('#horisontalbars').val();
        var verticalbars = jQuery('#verticalbars').val();

        var HS = (parseInt(horisontalbars)) + 1;
        var VS = (parseInt(verticalbars)) + 1;
        var S = HS * VS;
        var barPrice = S * 1.5; //default bar price 1.5

        jQuery("#bars").html("Center Post Price: " + barPrice);

        //total calculation
        var total = (parseFloat(framecolor)) + (parseFloat(handle)) + (parseFloat(glass)) +
            (parseFloat(barPrice)) + (parseFloat(postPrice));
        console.log(priceValue);
        jQuery("#total").html("Total Price: $ " + (parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(priceValue)));
    };
    $('#width,#height,#color,#glass,#handle,#centerposthorisontal,#centerpostvertical,#horisontalbars,#verticalbars,#total').on('change', Calculation);
});
```

Now before get the baseValue from ajax call the total will calculate

> After get the data from ajax call how to fire the other function

Comment: are you want to call     $('#width,#height,#color,#glass,#handle,#centerposthorisontal,#centerpostvertical,#horisontalbars,#verticalbars,#total').on('change', Calculation);
 function after getting response.

Comment: yes, otherwise total calculation not works correctly

Comment: You need to cal this functin in success of ajax and try

Comment: can u give me a answer please. im new to these stuff

Comment: just try in your success function of ajax like, .success(function(data) {
                priceValue = data.price_component;
                jQuery("#baseprice").html("Base Price: " + priceValue);

                Calculation();
            });

Comment: if i do like that there is no change

Comment: after doing that have you check caclulation function is call or not?